# ¿Cómo puedo remplazar comillas sencillas por espacio?

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

AL momento de ejecutar este código me marca error:

```
REPLACE DESC WITH STRTRAN(DESC,'''','')  ALL
```

¿A qué se debe?

---

[image: me sale ese error esta bien no?]
 no se porque me sale ese error :(
Soy nueva en fox pro lo siento

Answer (score 2):

ya encontré el error

```
REPLACE DESC WITH STRTRAN(DESC,"'",'') ALL
```

cambié las comillas simple por doble comillas y funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Debes escapar los caracteres ya que las comillas son caracteres especiales, tu código quedaria así:

```
REPLACE DESC WITH STRTRAN(DESC,'\'\'','')  ALL
```

[foxpro](/questions/tagged/foxpro)[visual-foxpro](/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro)

Comment: Gracias :3 eres un lindo

Comment: Si te he ayudado puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta e incluso puntuar :D.

Comment: me sale error :( me dice que me falta ")"

Comment: Supongo que las ultimas comillas las pones simples.. ' ' y un espacio en medio.

Comment: lo puse tal cual me lo pasaste ;(

Comment: escribe las comillas manualmente, no copies y pegues. Todas las comillas del código son simples.

Comment: me sale el error ese que puse en la captura aqui abajo ;(